# book about astronaut who crashed on moon, finds species underground waging war

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a sci-fi book about an astronaut who is led underground on the Moon. He finds two races of beings engaged in a "technical war" and the loser has people voluntarily die to equal number of losses in battle.

I had that book when I was a kid, it was probably written in the 1960s or 70s.

Comment: sorry. was a sci-fi book about an astronaut who crash landed on moon.  was written a long time ago, had when i was a kid, but lost it. would like to find it again.

Comment: Sounds more like a Star Trek episode: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Taste_of_Armageddon

Comment: book was written probably in 60's or 70's. something Asimov might write. just not sure. btw, i am 40! :)

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't one of the numbered Star Trek novels by James Blish that had all the episodes in a short story written form? Star Trek 2 had this in it, was published in 1968.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure this is 'The Lomokome Papers' by Herman Wouk

Comment: For the record, this has been confirmed correct in a deleted 'answer' by the OP. However, some [edit]s to explain **how and why** this story fits the description in the question would greatly improve your answer.